# INVALID_FIELD:Foreign key external ID: 0032000001ucgknaah not found for field Sandbox_Migration_Id__c in entity Contact:--

Tags: salesforce-id, talend

I am facing a weird behavior with talend.
I am trying to migrate events using talend bulk components.
I have migrate 99% of the data, but for the few left records, i get the following error:

> INVALID_FIELD:Foreign key external ID: 0032000001ucgknaah not found
>   for field Sandbox_Migration_Id__c in entity Contact:--

As you can see, it's reporting the lower case of the actual id of the contact.

I'm puzzled because it worked for most of the records except for few.
Does anybody have a clue about this?

thx

Comment: do you know what sql or call talend makes to get the data...does it checks two table linnked by foriegn key?

Comment: @garpitmzn Hi, sorry for the late reply, I was inspecting all this time but in vain. I'm using tSalesforceInput to get the data from Salesforce, and no check between 2 tables is made. The value of the foreign key is correct in the file generated by tSalesforceOutputBulk (it matches the id in the source org). But the output of tSalesforceBulkExec is a reject with the above error.